# Find all analytic functions such that $z^{2} f^{\prime \prime}(z)+f^{\prime}(z)-6 f(z)=0, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

This is a question I got in a homework sheet for one of my modules (MSc Mathematics, complex analysis module). We've been doing Taylor Series and Laurent series in class, and I tried to find the Taylor series for $f(z)$ about 0, and then differentiated that to get $f'(z)$ and $f''(z)$.

Then I substituted these into the given equation, and for the first few terms I got:

$$-6f(0) + (2-6z)f'(0) + (z^2+2z)f''(0) + ...$$

I hit a dead end after that. I don't know if what I've done is helpful, or if I'm completely on the wrong track. If anyone could advise me on whether this is going in the right direction or not, that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What is *the definition* of analytic functions given to you in the course?

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ essentially a complex function defined by a power series. So if the power series expansion is valid, it's analytic.

Comment: Hint: The coefficent of $z^{n}$ in the power series of LHS is $0$ for every $n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm. In fact the problem is very tricky

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Not really. Start with $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ and write down the the resulting equations for powers of $z$ up to $z^5$ or so, then the pattern should be obvious.

Comment: @MartinR So I've had a go at doing that, when substituting $f(z)$ into the equation I ended up with the following power series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\left(n+2\right)\left(n-3\right)a_n+\left(n+1\right)a_{n+1}\right)z^n=0$$

Then I think that for this to be true, we must have that each coefficient of $z^n$ is equal to zero? So I took the coefficient, equated it to zero and rearranged to obtain:

$$a_{n+1}=\left(\frac{6+n-n^2}{n+1}\right)a_n$$

I'm not sure how helpful this is? Would I just say that every f(z) must have a power series with coefficients like this?

Comment: @JulietTreip: You have removed $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  from the title. Please clarify if you are looking for solutions in $\Bbb C$, in a neighbourhood of the origin, or in arbitrary domains.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I ran out of space in the title and forgot to add it into the body of text. Yes I am still looking for solutions for :ℂ→ℂ

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ be the Taylor series of $f$ at $z=0$. Then
$$
 f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_nz^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_{n+1} z^n
$$
and
$$
 z^2 f''(z) = z^2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1) a_nz^{n-2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1) a_nz^n \, .
$$
If $f$ is a solution of the differential equation in a neighbourhood of the origin then
$$
 n(n-1) a_n + (n+1)a_{n+1} - 6a_n = 0
$$
must hold for all non-negative integers $n$, i.e.
$$ \tag{$*$}
 a_{n+1} = \frac{6 - n(n-1)}{n+1} a_n \, .
$$
In particular:
$$
 a_1 = 6 a_0\, , \\
a_2 = 3a_1 = 18 a_0\, , \\
a_3 = \frac 43 a_2 = 24a_0 \, , \\
a_4 = 0 \, ,
$$
and then $(*)$ implies that $a_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 4$.

So the only solutions of the differential equation which are analytic in a neighbourhood of the origin are the polynomials
$$
 f(z) = a_0 (1 + 6z + 18z^2 + 24z^3)
$$
with arbitrary $a_0 \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: I found more solutions... The general solution that I found is $f(z) = c_{2} \cdot \sqrt[z]{e} \cdot \left( 4 \cdot z - 1 \right) \cdot z^{2} + c_{2} \cdot \left( 6 \cdot z \cdot \left( 4 \cdot z^{2} + 3 \cdot z + 1 \right) + 1 \right)$ for $z \ne 0$ but your solution only covers the case $c_{2} = 0$ aka something is missing or is my solution wrong?.

Comment: @KevinDietrich: No, your solution is correct. My method gives all solutions which are analytic in a neighbourhood of  the origin (as I hopefully made clear). – The question originally asked for all solutions $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. As I now see, that part was later removed, but the question still mentions the “Taylor series of $f(z)$ about $0$.” I have left a comment at the question and asked the author for clarification.